# How to delete node from Firebase via REST API?

Tags: rest, curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase DB structure as follows.

[image]

I want to delete particular type via Firebase Rest API. I can delete a type2 using its name as follows.

```
curl -X DELETE \
  'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/ds_api/types/type2.json'
```

But I want to delete type2 by using its id `id =2`. How can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Firebase SDKs and APIs are the same in this respect: you can only delete a node once you know its path.

That means you'll need to first query to determine the exact path of your node:

```
curl 'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/ds_api/types.json?orderBy="id"&equalTo=2'
```

This will give you the `type2` node, which you can then pass to the `DELETE` request.

Comment: `curl 'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/ds_api/types.json?orderBy="id"&equalTo=2' `

returns following error. Why is that?

`"error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"id\", for path \"/ds_api/types\", to the rules"`

Comment: As the error message hints, you'll need to add an index. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data